# package `bumpalo v3.15.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.73.0 or newer

Tags: solana-program

*package `bumpalo v3.15.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.73.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.73.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p bumpalo@3.15.4 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `bumpalo` supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev*

my version

- solana-cli 1.18.6
- rustc 1.76.0
- cargo 1.76.0

Answer (score 0):

1-
if you use ubuntu you should search old rustc in /.local/share/solana
and replace it with newer version.

second soloution:
run "cargo build-sbf --version" and if your solana version not updated update it with "solana-install init" to "newest version"